# Is 4.1 the best for this 4? yr old device?

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, device-firmware

In my pile of devices I have what looks like a "Galaxy Tab 2 10.1". I believe it is 4?? years old.

It has 4.1.2.  When I try to update, it looks like I cannot update any further.

1) Is there a way to determine what the hell device / model year this is?

2) If I know the model year/etc.  **How can I tell what is the "maximum" Android version?**

3) In fact, **is there a way** to update this device?  It seems bizarre I can't update it further - it's pretty new.

4) Do I perhaps need to ***update the firmware*** in some way?

[image]

[image]

[image]

What's the story here.  Thanks very much in advance to all.

Comment: @JoeBlow: the community support for that device is so good that even after ~4 years, latest Android version (Marshmallow -> CM13) is under development. It is unofficial but is there. You should be able to find a *stable* Android 5.1.1 ROM for your device. See http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-2/10-inch-development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 years is ancient in tech years. Your first pic holds your answers. The model Gt-p5110 and with Google it states that it was released in 2012. Came with android ice cream sandwich 4.0.3 and it is upgradable to android jelly bean 4.2.2. Also if you look at the kernel version you will notice that it was compiled in 2013. For update firmware you could check sammobile.com or similar sites.

To find your model number, look in the middle right of the screen shown in the first screenshot. The field marked "Model Number:" tells you the model number.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks. It seems to be stuck on 4.1.2 (not 4.2.2). Could it be (wild guess) I have to use "Keis" (ie, on a tethered PC) to make the next update?  Secondly, when I look here http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-P5110/ I think I bought the machine in France of all places. Notice it is 4.1.2 for France (4.2 elsewhere) -- is that the explanation there?  Finally, you've very kindly told me it is a "GT-5110".  Awesome - thanks. How the heck did you know that?   I've noticed on other Samsung, it tells you during the startup - this one does not tell you during startup.

Comment: Oh.  I guess where it says ***MODEL NUMBER*** in large letters in the middle of the screen shot, that would do it   :)